# <button> padding / width problem

Tags: css, rendering, width, padding

I'm using `<button>`  to make a post request in a form. I also styled a `a.button` exactly like the `<button>` (I need the `a.button` to make some JS stuff).

The button has some padding, a fixed height. When I do specify the width of the button / a they both look the same. But when I add width to the `<button>` it ignores the padding.

I'm having this problem in Chrome, Firefox and Opera, so I guess it's not a rendering fault. Also same issue with `<input type="submit" />`

Here is the basic CSS:

```
.button, button {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
    background: #ddd;
    font: 12px Verdana;
    padding: 40px; /* 40px, so you can see that it won't be rendered with width */
    text-align: center;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="button">Some text</a>
<button>Some text</button>
<!-- Works fine till here -->
<br /><br />
<a href="#" class="button" style="width:200px">Some text</a>
<button style="width:200px">Some text</button>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9dtnz/

Any suggestions why the browsers are ignoring the padding? (top and bottom when using height / left and right when using width).

Comment: This looks fine for me in FF 5.0

Comment: It doesn't in Chrome 12 and FF4

Comment: its working proper which version of browser you are using?

Comment: Do the two last buttons have the same outerWidth? They don't in Chrome 12, FF 4 & Opera 10.5

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Very weird, I've seen my Chrome has a `box-sizing: border-box;` rule for input elements, so padding is included in width...

So to avoid that just specify `box-sizing: content-box;` (some prefix can be necessary).

Comment: Thank you very much! This solves the problem. `-webkit-box-sizing: initial` did the job

Comment: I did a bit of research and initial doesn't seem to work in Opera & FF. This does: [prefix]-`box-sizing: content-box;`

Comment: yup, I've just tested on chrome. I think it will be useful for some people =)

Comment: Still true in 2018 for Firefox and Chrome (both recognize the standard box-sizing property without prefix now). I'm curious to know WHY both browsers use a different default box-sizing for form elements. This is rather counter-intuitive...

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine to me, so it might be a style sheet conflict issue. Try using !important to override whatever it may be and that could solve your problem.

```
.button, button {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
    background: #ddd;
    font: 12px Verdana;
    padding: 40px!important; /* 40px, so you can see that it won't be rendered with width */
    text-align: center;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Michael.

Comment: Nope, no difference with !important. Here is a screenshot of what I see: http://cl.ly/261Z1T2C2Z0F44471f2y . The two last buttons should've the same outerWidth, but they don't.