# Button Padding Not Working

Tags: html, css, button, padding

I have an image banner which I'm trying to add a button on top of it. The button is in HTML format and not an image. However, the problem is that I'm unable to move the button on top of the image. I believe it has to do with the margin of the button. I've implemented the following codes into my Weebly website, and though the button seems to fit perfectly well inside the editor, after publishing, the button displays on the bottom of the banner. Here is my HTML code:

The "margin:-70px" seems to be correct, though it doesn't apply after publishing. So what's wrong? Is there something missing?

```css
.btn_action_1 {
  border: 5px solid #000 !important;
  /* Change button border color */
  color: #000 !important;
  /* Change button text color */
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  line-height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn_action_1 span {
  left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  -moz-transition: all .4s;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.btn_action_1 .ico_arrow {
  background: url(ico_arrow_w.png) 0 center no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 17px;
  width: 17px;
  position: relative;
  left: -12px;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  -moz-transition: all .4s;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.btn_action_1:hover {
  background: #000 !important;
  /* Change button background color when mouse over */
  color: #fff !important;
  /* Change button text color when mouse over */
}

.btn_action_1:hover span {
  left: -5px;
}

.btn_action_1:hover .ico_arrow {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  left: 5px;
}

@media (max-width: 479px) {
  .btn_action_1 {
    padding: 18px 30px;
  }
}

.btn_action_1:not(:hover)>.hover,
.btn_action_1:hover>.default {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<img src="http://unlckpaypal.weebly.com/uploads/6/3/8/8/63884033/left_banner.png" style="margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;width:440px;height:210px;">

<a href="http://unlckpaypal.weebly.com/trending-127809.html" style="margin:-70px 0px 0px 200px;width:180px;height:45px;" class="btn_action_1">
  <span>SHOP NOW</span>
  <i class="ico_arrow"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: I recommend you abandon this approach and use the image as a background to (say) a div, then simply put the button on top.

Comment: I think the padding is working fine see i added js fiddle in my answer

Comment: can you show the image of how you want the output to be?

Comment: here is a screenshot: http://unlckpaypal.weebly.com/uploads/6/3/8/8/63884033/x.png

Comment: Specifying the padding with **important** resolved getting button padding to work in my case, eg: `40px!important`. Thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6790573/2162226

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this code to `padding: 10px 15px 10px;` to `.btn_action_1 span` this class, I think it will work

```css
.btn_action_1 {
border: 5px solid #000 !important; /* Change button border color */
color: #000 !important; /* Change button text color */
font-size: 22px;
font-family: 'Ubuntu';
line-height: 0;
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px 15px 10px;
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
z-index: 3;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.btn_action_1 span {
left: 10px;
position: relative;
-o-transition: all .4s;
-moz-transition: all .4s;
-webkit-transition: all .4s;
transition: all .4s;
}
.btn_action_1 .ico_arrow {
background: url(ico_arrow_w.png) 0 center no-repeat;
display: inline-block;
height: 17px;
width: 17px;
position: relative;
left: -12px;
top: 0px;
opacity: 0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
-o-transition: all .4s;
-moz-transition: all .4s;
-webkit-transition: all .4s;
transition: all .4s;
}

.btn_action_1:hover {
background: #000 !important; /* Change button background color when mouse over */
color: #fff !important; /* Change button text color when mouse over */
}

.btn_action_1:hover span {
left: -5px;
}
.btn_action_1:hover .ico_arrow {
opacity: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
left: 5px;
}
@media (max-width: 479px) {
.btn_action_1 {
    padding: 18px 30px;
}
}

.btn_action_1:not(:hover)>.hover,
.btn_action_1:hover>
.default {display:none}
```

```html
<img src="http://unlckpaypal.weebly.com/uploads/6/3/8/8/63884033/left_banner.png" 
style="margin: 10px 0px -50px 0px;width:440px;height:210px; position:relative;">

<a href="http://unlckpaypal.weebly.com/trending-127809.html" 
style="margin:-30px 10px 10px 220px;width:180px;height:45px;  " 
class="btn_action_1">
<span>SHOP NOW</span>
<i class="ico_arrow"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: I'm not talking about the button's padding. I'm talking about its margin. The button must be aligned right underneath the text. I need to move the button a little bit upwards.

Comment: yes now it seems okay. let me try to implement the code from my side

Answer (score 1):

Just add this class

```
.img-wrapper .btn_action_1{

  display:block;
  margin-top:-100px

}
```

Fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/ov9rxuys/

Comment: thank you @Tariq Javed, now everything works great! (-: I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

i recommend using absolute position for the button since there is no alternative

```
.btn_action_1 {
  position: absolute; /* remove margin from HTML if possible */
  bottom: 20px; /* adjust as you want it to be */
  right: 50px; /* adjust as you want it to be */
}
```

i have jsfiddle for it https://jsfiddle.net/Ls6coLb7/

Comment: working perfectly. Thx. This was driving me nuts all day long. I guess I'll have to start learning some coding. (-:

Comment: yeah, sure you do :D btw don't forget to mark best answer among all the answers that you find, so that it will be useful for future reference